# Exporting Predicted object coordination in CSV/Excel

Tags: python, computer-vision, object-detection, yolov8

%cd /content/drive/MyDrive/Classes/YOLOv8

!yolo predict model=runs/detect/train2/weights/best.pt source=data/test/images save=True

In YOLOv8, I use the code above to predict objects.

Is it possible to export predicted object coordination in csv or excel?